# Выборка sql из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Здравствуйте. Есть задача вывести каждую последнюю картинку для каждой записи клуба. Решал задачу так, но выводит для каждой записи клуба последнюю картинку из всей бд. Понимаю что нету связи по `id`, но как решить - не знаю.

```
select db_club.*, db_images.name as iName
from `db_club`, `db_images` 
where db_club.type = '1' 
    and db_club.type = db_images.type 
    and db_images.id = (
        select max(db_images.id) 
        from db_images, db_club 
        where db_images.type = db_club.type and db_images.type = '1'
    ) 
order by db_club.id desc
```

Пробовал еще так. В этом случае идет вывод из нужного клуба но первая картинка. А нужна последняя.

```
select db_club.*, db_images.name as iName
from `db_club`, `db_images` 
where db_club.type = '1' 
    and db_club.type = db_images.type 
    and db_images.bdid = db_club.id
group by db_images.bdid
order by db_club.id desc
```

Структуры таблици db_club
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структуры таблици db_images
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В внутренний подзапрос первого варианта добавьте `group by db_images.type` и уберите от туда таблицу db_club, она там не нужна

Comment: Попробуйте переделать запрос используя LEFT JOIN

Comment: И совершенно не ясно почему вы связываете таблицы по полю type. было бы логично если бы там участвовал db_club.id ( и по нему group by делать для максимума). Но я в вшей структуре не вижу каким бы полем images на него сослался бы

Comment: И отлаживайте запросы частями, берете внутринний подзпрос, добиваетесь что бы он выдавал нужные максимльные значения, потом его уже ставите в основной

Comment: @Mike `bdid` в images => `id` в club. type нужен для определения страницы, он здесь как доп. поле и не участвует в выборе последней картинки.

Comment: @Mike select db_club.*, db_images.name as iName
        from `db_club`, `db_images` 
        where db_club.type = '1' 
         and db_club.type = db_images.type 
         and db_images.id = (
          select max(db_images.id) 
          from db_images
          where db_images.type = '1'
          group by db_images.type
         ) 
        order by db_club.id desc

Comment: @Mike Сделал с group by, выводит так же только последнюю картинку из всей `db_images`

Comment: Со связью таблиц сначала разберитесь. очень странно что бы их связиваете по некому полю type которое первичным ключем не является и вы пытаетесь брать все картинки для типа 1, а не для конкретного клуба

Comment: @Mike Свзять идет по первичному `id`, `type` это просто идентификатор страницы т.к. в таблице картинок хранятся все картинки, не только для клуба. Если вам будет комфортно - можете вообще его убрать из запроса.

Comment: Я не вижу этой связи, я вижу `db_club.type = db_images.type` но должно быть `db_club.id=db_images.что-то` и group by тогда вот по этому же `db_images.что-то` т.е. в разрезе клуба

Comment: @Mike Отредактировал пост. Посмотрите второй способ. Выводиться как нужно, но осталось вывести последнюю картинку, а не первую.

Comment: Второй вариант в принципе работать правильно не может. он берет даже не первую, а первую попавшуюся картинку (вам просто везет что она именно первая). отредактированный первый способ рабочий, привел в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select db_club.*, db_images.name as iName
  from `db_club`, `db_images` 
 where db_club.type = 1
   and db_club.type = db_images.type
   and db_images.bdid = db_club.id
   and db_images.id IN (
        select max(id) from db_images
         where type = 1
         group by bdid
       ) 
 order by db_club.id desc
```

Только такой вариант не выведет клубы для которых нет ни одной картинки, если это не верно, используйте LEFT JOIN вместо запятой.